# Apache Airflow - rest API Authentication

Tags: rest, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to trigger my dag with AirFlow rest API. However not able to understand how to do authentication.

Following URL works fine from my browser.

http://localhost:8181/api/experimental/dags/demo/dag_runs

However, Following code gives Authentication Error.

```py
import requests
import json
from pprint import pprint


result = requests.get(
  "http://localhost:8181/api/experimental/dags/demo/dag_runs",
  data=json.dumps("{}"),
  auth=("myuser", "mypassword"))
pprint(result.content.decode('utf-8'))
```

I found this as well, but now sure how to pass auth

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/api/client/api_client.py

Answer (score 0):

By default the REST API rejects all requests.  Make sure to set up the API auth backend as described in the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/api.html):

```
[api]
auth_backend = airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth
```

Answer (score 0):

In newest Airflow 2 versions, default is to check the session https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/api.html#api-authentication

```
[api]
auth_backends = airflow.api.auth.backend.session
```

So your browser can access the API because it probably keeps a cookie-based session but any other client will be unauthenticated.

Use an alternative auth backend if you need automated access to the API, up to [cooking your own](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/api.html#roll-your-own-api-authentication).

**Security disclaimer:** using `airflow.api.auth.backend.default` disables authentication, posing a security risk on publicly accessible Airflow webservers.

Answer (score -1):

1.- You should verify that the authentication is working on your UI:

http://localhost:8181/api/experimental/dags/demo/dag_runs

This link should require authentication.

2.- The request code snippet you could try is the following:

```
curl --user USER_NAME:USER_PASSWORD -X POST \
http://localhost:8181/api/experimental/dags/demo/dag_runs \
-H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d "{}"
```

Similar code in node: https://godatadriven.com/blog/using-the-airflow-experimental-rest-api-to-trigger-a-dag/